# vuetify change tab event

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

I use v-tabs and I want to know: how can i know about tab id, when I change a tab?
this is my code:

```
 <v-tabs class="tabs-container" color="green" grow>
        <v-tab class="tab"
               v-for="tab of tabs"
               :key="tab.id"
               :title=tab>
            {{tab.name}}
        </v-tab>
        <v-tabs-items>
        <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id">
            <div v-if='tab.id == 0'>
                <CreateHero v-on:updateAllTabs="updateAllTabs"/>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <HeroPresenter/>
            </div>
        </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
    </v-tabs>

...
    methods: {
            updateAllTabs() {
                axios.get('/hero').then(responce => {
                    this.tabs = responce.data
                })
            },
            getHero(id) {
                this.$emit("getCurrentHero", id);
            }
        }
```

so, when a click to tab, I want to send tab id in the HeroPresenter component. I tried to use $emit, but what should I write in v-tab?? My vue-component HeroPresenter was subscribed on "getCurrentHero"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add a click event, which will call your function

```
<v-tab class="tab"
    v-for="tab of tabs"
    :key="tab.id"
    :title=tab
    @click="getHero(tab.id)"
>
```

Comment: There is a change event in the API documentation. Isn't there any way to use it?

Comment: @AK12 there is but that wasn't the OP question

Comment: @therealak12
<v-tabs @change="changeTab">
And add a method changeTab(tab). The tab will be passed automatically as index or key if there is one.